# Extending objects living in my namespace

Tags: javascript, inheritance, namespaces

I'm developing a little library which is slowly growing to be not so little. For that reason I decided to put all my functions into `myNamespace` to avoid ugly conflicts and split into separate files to make it easier to manage the code. Unfortunately, when I did that I broke some things that used to work before - namely extending the functionality of an Array object. That was my initial approach that DOESN'T work:

```
if(myNamespace === undefined) {
  var myNamespace = {};
}

myNamespace.myArray = {
    height: 0,
    width: 0
};

myNamespace.myArray.prototype = [];
```

Now when I do:

```
testArray = myNamespace.myArray;
```

I can't seem to be able to do:

```
testArray.push("test");
```

How can I fix that? What is the best approach to encapsulating code in a namespace?
I'm pretty sure that it's just me confusing defined/instantiated objects, but I simply don't know the proper way to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly broke? The code you've posted now doesn't really show any actual functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably make it a bit more clear. I'll edit the question.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/KavXu/).

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a namespace issue, as that code doesn't work with or without the myNamespace. prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a namespace issue - it's about how you're defining and instantiating your class. Classes are defined as a functions, not as object literals:

```
// define your class
ns.MyArray = function(w, h) {
   this.width = w;
   this.height = h;
};

// set the class prototype
ns.MyArray.prototype = [];

// instantiate
var a = new ns.MyArray(5,10);
a.push("Test");
a.length; // 1
a[0]; // "Test"
a.width; // 5
```

What you're doing is just creating an object literal and then assigning it to the `testArray` variable, same as this:

```
var o = {};
var testArray = o;
testArray == o; // true
```

I'm not sure if I would have expected this behavior, but it looks like assigning the `prototype` of an object literal like `{width:0, height:0}` adds a normal field with the key "prototype" - the actual `prototype` is still `Object`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just starting to play with javascript and still struggle with its syntax.